# Installing MS MPI with GNU C++

Tags: c++, windows, installation, mpi

I've installed GNU C++ and MS MPI on my Win7. I've confirmed that C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin folder with MPI is in the PATH for System Variables.  What are the next steps I should do to start compiling and running parallel programs using 1) bare cmd line and 2) Code::Blocks IDE? If I just try to compile the "MPI Hello World" program it does not recognize mpi.h header file. THANKS SO MUCH!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     MPI::Init(argc, argv);
     int num_procs = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
     int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
     std::cout << "Hello world from process " << rank << " of " << num_procs << "\n";
     MPI::Finalize();
     return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Code::Blocks, nor have I used GCC on Windows, so this advice may be worth about what you're paying for it. But since no one else has answered up, I'll give it a shot.

Assuming you have the latest Microsoft MPI installed (v7, available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49926 ; note that there are two installers and you'll want to install them both), this command line should build your sample app:

```
g++ -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" -o myprog.exe myprog.cpp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib"
```

Execute it with:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe" -n 3 myprog.exe
```

I suppose Code::Blocks has places to add include and library paths and libraries. You'll want to add the above SDK paths above to the appropriate locations, and add msmpi.lib to the link libraries.

One other note: Your sample code is using the C++ MPI bindings. These were deprecated in MPI v2 and removed in MPI v3. I don't know if Microsoft MPI supports them, but I'd recommend sticking with the C bindings instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to reply. I've tried it and couldn't build the app since <sal.h> is missing. If I google it , it seems that I need to install MS Visual Studio. Gosh.